# facing issues about array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql

I am implementing a program in rails where there is a form and after submitting the form it will check if there is any record with duplicate value for a specific field in database. My database table is students. So my corresponding model name is Student. I am writing this code (what I have just discussed) in my controller.
But I am facing the following error. I am using some arrays for internal operations. When I wrote that particular function in ruby only(not rails) then it was working fine. Moreover I am also facing error due to the use of "length".

My error is:
NoMethodError in StudentsController#create

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

My controller code is:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

 def new
    @student=Student.new
    @students=Student.all
 end

 def create
    @student=Student.new(u_params)
    ret_val=string_check
    if ret_val==1
        @student.save
        redirect_to new_student_path , :notice => "Inserted!!!"

    else
        redirect_to new_student_path , :notice => "Match,Not inserted!!!"
    end
 end


 def u_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:id ,:firstname, :lastname)
 end

 def u_params_second
  params.require(:student).permit(:firstname)
 end

 def string_check
    count =0;
    #temp1=:firstname
    temp1=params[:firstname]
    supplied_val=temp1

    puts "Entered in string_check method"
    for i in 46..100


       temp2=Student.find_by(id:i)
       table_val=temp2.firstname


        size1=supplied_val.to_s.length
        size2=table_val.to_s.length

        arr1=Array.new
        arr2=Array.new

        # arr1[i] ||= []
        # arr2[i] ||= []

        for i in 0..size1

            arr1.push(supplied_val[i])
        end

        for i in 0..size2

            arr2.push(table_val[i])
        end


        for i in 0..size1
            if arr1[i]=="@" || arr1[i]=="#" || arr1[i]=="{" || arr1[i]=="}" || arr1[i]=="(" || arr1[i]==")" || arr1[i]=="[" || arr1[i]=="]" || arr1[i]=="." || arr1[i]==";" || arr1[i]=="," || arr1[i]=="%" || arr1[i]=="&" || arr1[i]=="*" || arr1[i]=="!" || arr1[i]=="?" || arr1[i]=="$" || arr1[i]=="^" || arr1[i]==":" || arr1[i]=="-" || arr1[i]=="/"
                count=count+1
                # puts count
                arr1[i]=""
            end
        end
        # puts arr1
        puts arr1.join
        final1=arr1.join



        for i in 0..size2
            if arr2[i]=="@" || arr2[i]=="#" || arr2[i]=="{" || arr2[i]=="}" || arr2[i]=="(" || arr2[i]==")" || arr2[i]=="[" || arr2[i]=="]" || arr2[i]=="." || arr2[i]==";" || arr2[i]=="," || arr2[i]=="%" || arr2[i]=="&" || arr2[i]=="*" || arr2[i]=="!" || arr2[i]=="?" || arr2[i]=="$" || arr2[i]=="^" || arr2[i]==":" || arr2[i]=="-" || arr2[i]=="/"
                count=count+1
                # puts count
                arr2[i]=""
            end
        end
        # puts arr2
        puts arr2.join
        final2=arr2.join

        if final1==final2
            flag=0
        else
            flag=1
        end
        return flag
    end

   end
end
```

The routes.rb file is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

   resources :students
end
```

Comment: show me your routes and view file and also do puts "#{ @student.to_json}"

Comment: Can you share the detail that on which line you are getting `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` error ?

Comment: unrelated to your issue but consider using Array#Include? instead of the long ORs. e.g `if ["@", "#", "{" , ... etc].include?(arr1[i])`

Comment: Also, do not use `for`, it is extremely un-Ruby. Use `map` or `each` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> My error is: NoMethodError in StudentsController#create
>
> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

It simply means that you are trying to access something as an array that is actually a `nil` object, and not an array.

To get rid of this error, you can a technique called short-circuit in Ruby.

Let's say your following piece of code is producing the said error:

```
arr1[i]
```

You can use an `if` condition like this:

```
if arr1
  arr1[i]
end
```

Or use short-circuit technique like this:

```
arr1 && arr1[i]
```

Comment: Are you still facing the same error? And you have applied `&&` everywhere you are using an array, and you are not sure that the array could be a `nil` object.

Comment: I have used the first if approach ...Since I am using another if with multiple OR statement then how to use the && option there?..please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that the relevant code snippet was working for ruby and it's not for rails, the problem is most likely due to variable `i` used at inner and outer loops both. In any case, this needs to be fixed first or else it will result in unexpected behaviour only.

Outer Loops:

```
for i in 46..100
```

Inner Loops:

```
for i in 0..size1
for i in 0..size2
...
```

Keep `i` for outer loop and change the inner loop iterator to `j`

Hope it Helps : )

Comment: you have changed ALL the relevant `i`'s and `j`'s right and still didn't work? Well, this may not be the only problem. But if this is not fixed, it surely will keep causing unexpected behaviour.

Comment: yeah sure...Thank you for bringing my attention there.I missed it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers of @harish and @arslan, there may be a case where, 
**`temp2=Student.find_by(id:i)` may fail because there may not be a student with that id.**

So, temp2 may return nil at that time.

```
for i in 0..size2
   arr2.push(table_val[i]) // this may get failed
end
```

Then arr2.push will not work because table_val[i] is nil, so there are chances of undefined method [] for nil class.